# How to initialize datetimepicker with current value in the inputbox

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, datetimepicker

I want to initialize datetime picker with current value in the input box in the backbone view js file for which I have written following code in the afterRender function. This is not working.

```
afterRender: function() {
        this.$el.find('.time').datetimepicker({
            lazyInit : true, // Lazy init to prevent a lot of instances right away
            datepicker : false,
            format : 'g:i A',
            formatTime: 'g:i A',
            defaultTime: $(this).val(),
            step: 1
        });
}
```

And also I wanted to populate time field in my dust file with capital AM/PM using @format, but currently it is rendering with small am/pm in the field with the following code.

```
<input type="text" id="eventTime" name="eventTime" 
class="event_form time changewidth" data-error-style="tooltip" 
style="width:90px;" skip_element="true" 
value="{@format style="time" value=eventDateLocal pattern="h:mm a"/}" 
oninput="eventStartTime.dataset.value=eventStartTime.value +' ' + eventTime.value"/>
```

Comment: What is `afterRender`? Which datetime picker are you using? There are lots of them.

Comment: afterRender is a callback function which gets called after initialize callback in backbone view.js files. I am using http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/, I have identified issue with this picker, if time in my field has small letters for AM/PM then it is not getting initialized with that time.

Comment: There is no such thing as `afterRender` in [Backbone.View](http://backbonejs.org/#View).

Comment: This is a custom method which we created by extending backbone. It essentially get called after page is rendered to perform some activities on rendered elements.